# Microsoft Access - Using DSum() to get a running total based on multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to do a running total based on a component part and a date. The base table consists of requirements per component per date. I want to do a running some per component for each of the date records that component contains.

Current result using RunTot: DSum("[SumOfQty Remaining to Reserve]","[Component by Start Date - ACM]","[SiteItemID]<=" & [SiteItemAlias] & "") :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXjql.png)

What I want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khh43.png)

Answer (score 0):

Compare the date:

```
RunTot: DSum("[SumOfQty Remaining to Reserve]","[Component by Start Date - ACM]","[Start] <= #" & Format([Start], "yyyy\/mm\/dd) & "#")
```